# Como puedo convertir la hora que tengo en decimales a horas y minutos en C#

Tags: c#

Esta es la función que tengo para calcular las horas trabajadas pero lo tengo en decimal y estoy intentando pasarlo a hora y minuto, estuve intentando de varias formas pero me lo sigue dando en decimal.

```
    private double Calcular_Totalhoras_trabajadas(DateTime horaingreso)
    {

        DateTime horaSalida = DateTime.Now;
        //calculamos la diferencia del tiempo

        TimeSpan diferencia = horaSalida - horaingreso;
        //Obtenemos el total de horas:

        double Totalhoras = diferencia.TotalHours;



        return Totalhoras;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Juan, como te lo devuelve?

Comment: Asi como esta lo devuelve en decimal, ejemplo la entrada fue de 08:00:33 y su salida fue 15:42:37 y la hora trabajada da 7.7013798105555

Answer (score 2):

Es que en tu función lo estas devolviendo como un `double` por eso te lo devuelve así.

Intenta convirtiendo ese `double` en un `string`, tanto como en el tipo de función que es.

```
private string Calcular_Totalhoras_trabajadas(DateTime horaingreso)
{
    DateTime horaSalida = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan diferencia = horaSalida - horaingreso;
    double Totalhoras = diferencia.TotalHours;

    // Formatear el valor de Totalhoras como una cadena en el formato de hora
    string totalHorasFormateadas = TimeSpan.FromHours(Totalhoras).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

    return totalHorasFormateadas;
}
```

Comment: No es necesario hacer esto : `TimeSpan.FromHours(Totalhoras)` `diferencia` ya es un `TimeSpan` por lo que esto es suficiente `string totalHorasFormateadas = diferencia.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");`

Comment: Al momento de que me de el resultado tendria que cambiar mi tipo de dato de mi base de datos, ya que en este momento mi tipo de dato lo tengo en double tendria que pasarlo al tipo time?

Comment: Hola Juan, tal vez se te paso incluir esa información en tu pregunta jeje, si es así, es un sí. Para guardar un tipo de dato de Fecha lo tienes que guardar como Date, es lo ideal.

Comment: @JuanMartinez No tiene sentido lo que indicas, si tienes un tipo numérico en la base de datos, como pretendías guardarlo en horas y minutos como tu pregunta lo indica??

Answer (score 0):

En C# los metodos, las clases que ofrece, resuelven, y son potentes, esta genial como lenguaje multinivel. De hecho, puede ser asi simplemente perfecto.

No obstante C# también permite hacer todo a bajo nivel, si quieres. Esto pasa por tratar de desarrollar codigo propio, para hacer mas cosas y usar menos recursos disponibles de medio alto nivel.

Esto, también funcionaría, aunque hace lo mismo, pero operando.

```
private string Calcular_Totalhoras_trabajadas(DateTime horaingreso)
    {    
        DateTime horaSalida = DateTime.Now;
            
        TimeSpan diferencia = horaSalida - horaingreso;
          
        Int TotalMinutos = diferencia.TotalMinutes;   

        return ""+(TotalMinutos/60)+:+(TotalMinutos%60)

    }
```

O bien
...

```
private string Calcular_Totalhoras_trabajadas(DateTime horaingreso)
    {    
        DateTime horaSalida = DateTime.Now;
            
        TimeSpan diferencia = horaSalida - horaingreso;
          
        Int TotalSegundos = diferencia.TotalSeconds;   

        return ""+Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDouble(TotalSegundos)/3600)+:+((TotalSegundos/60)%60)+":"+(TotalSegundos%60)

    }
```